# How to turn startup chime off on a iMac G5 under Gentoo

Tags: linux, mac, audio, boot, gentoo

I have a iMac G5 only with Gentoo installed on it and every time I turn it on, it plays the startup chime.

I already have my headset plugged in but this doesn't mute the sound.

Is there a way to turn it off using the Open Firmware or, if this isn't possible, could a script do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the *sys-apps/powerpc-utils* package, then you need to use the *nvsetvol* tool. Depending on the mac, you'll either want a value of 0 or 24 to turn off the volume. Beware that it will reset if you dual-boot to OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use [StartupSound.prefPane](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~arcana/StartupSound/index.en.html), but this is a Mac OS X program. You can hold the mute key after powering on to prevent the chime from playing for that boot, but I don't know of a Gentoo-specific way to do this.

Comment: I don't have my original keyboard anymore and even if I had it, would gentoo recognizes the mute key ?

Comment: @Studer, the EFI (akin to the “BIOS” on (older) PCs) plays the startup chime and recognizes boot keys. The EFI will search for an OS and start booting it only after the chime.

Comment: @Chris EFI didn't exist on mac hardware until the Intel transition--at the time of the G5, it was Open Firmware.

Comment: See my seperate answer in this question, showing how to use the NVRAM volume via nvsetvol. If you're creative, you can also do it manually in OpenFirmware.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a Mac, but try to add a line in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

Comment: The kernel is not running when that sound plays.